# Segue With NSUserDefaults + NSCoder Object

Tags: ios, segue, nscoder, nskeyedunarchiver

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
     if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowWordDetailsTwo"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = nil;
        Words *word = nil;
        indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        word = [myFavsTwo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

         DetailsViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
         destViewController.word = word;
    }
}
```

I'm getting a crash on segue -- breakpoint at:

```
     destViewController.word = word;
```

but if I "continue" on my debugger everything will work as normal -- the app just seems to be getting hung up on this line...

I think it's got to do with my object being part of NSUserDefaults with NSCoder...

how can I make it so that the app doesn't crash?!

I'm not getting any error message just a break point error

Comment: Just to clarify.. you didn't make the breakpoint, it crashes on that line and creates a breakpoint?

Comment: yeah that's right it crashes on that line and creates a breakpoint (thread 1, breakpoint 5.1)

Comment: @Soule fixed it thanks to your message -- can you write up an answer and I'll award you the credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just clarifying,

Did you create the breakpoint yourself, or was it autocreated by the debugger?

Try disabling the breakpoint to see if it works.